# UNET machmaking: What Unet Id is for?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I have made a test project using Network Manager, and unity multiplayer service. It works perfectly on PC, but android device does not see list of servers.

After couple of hours searching internet, all I have found is that I have to supply Unet ID. I have found the ID in the Unity Dashboard, but.. what the hell do I do with it now? There is a ton of abandoned questions & threads all over the internet, and no answer. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly, uNet is now deprecated, and was never really fully supported/working.

It is strongly advised to look for other solutions especially if you need matchmaking. I would recommand photon:

there is a new version that just came out: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/pun-2-free-119922

or you have the old version: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/photon-unity-networking-classic-free-1786

Comment: Well, it sucks that I have all the stuff ready and working, and now have to redo it, but oh well. Thanks for the answer, I guess I'll migrate to Photon.